# Counting empty Elements in foreach from xml

Tags: powershell

So i have a XML File which i read and iterate through with a foreach loop.

so far so good. 
Now i need to check if an Object is empty so i can prompt the User to Enter the Info.

right now i have to check every Object by Name if it is Empty.

```
foreach($var in $xml){
    if(!$var.Object1){$count++}
    if(!$var.Object2){$count++}

    do{
     more Stuff depending on the count Value
    }
    while($i -ne $count
}
```

as you can see i this will be a long list fast, depending how big your xml file is.
I don't want to write out every Object Name. 
I am wondering if i can just get the amount of objects and then loob through it if one of it is empty
somehwat like this

```
foreach($var in $xml){
  $c = $var.count
  for(i=1; $i -le $c; $i++){
    if(!$var.object$i){$count++}
  } 

do{
   more Stuff depending on the count Value
}
while($i -ne $count
}
```

i could save a lot of lines. But i can't figure out how to do this or if this is even Possible...
at the moment i refuse to belive that you HAVE to ask every single Object if it is Empty.

I dumped down this script to a few lines. The actual Script is a bit larger. (the do part has around 25 lines) But i wanted to keep it as small as possible.

If it is neccessary i can post my whole Script.

thanks in advance and Regards

Answer (score 0):

For this you're going to want to first load your XML into an XML object.

```
$path = "$env:temp\myFile.xml"
$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($Path)
```

from here you can traverse the nodes and select whatever information you need from them

```
#e.g.
$xml.Devices.Servers | Select-Object -Property Name, SerialNumber, IP
```

What you'd specifically be looking for in your case though is any object with a `$null` value. So you would do something like:

```
$xml.Devices.Servers | Where-Object {[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Name)}
```

This returns either a `$True` or `$False`. Then we do our conditionals from there.

Comment: That looks promising.
I will take a look at this and try to implemnt it into my Code. 

thank you very much so far. I guess i would never thought of it to use where-object
Well i'm still an amature xD